# How do i add path in python docx?

Tags: python

I am trying to add a path in this code, how do i do it? I dont understand it.

```
# folder path
data_folder = Path("Desktop\biologi")

if y == ('biologi'):
    document = Document() #create blank document
    document.save(y+(x.strftime(" %Y-%m-%d"))+".docx") #save blank document, lägg in path här
    document = Document(y+(x.strftime(" %Y-%m-%d"))+".docx") #open document
    p = document.add_paragraph()
    p.add_run(str(y+(x.strftime(" %Y-%m-%d"))))#edit words
    document.save(y+(x.strftime(" %Y-%m-%d"))+".docx")#save edited document

´´´
```

Comment: What do you mean `add a path`? The code looks like it's trying to resolve the location of the user's `Desktop` folder. Or are you trying to save in an existing folder in the user's desktop?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes i am trying to save in an existing folder

Comment: The path you used is relative which means it will only work if your Python code executes in the user's home folder, ie `c:Users\username`. The location of the home path, application data folders, `My Documents` are well-defined in Windows and can be retrieved either through environment variables or system calls. Sarmad's asnwer shows how to retrieve the `Desktop` folder's location for the current user

Comment: In general documents should go to `My Documents`, not the user's Desktop. Application data goes to the paths pointed to by the `%APPDATA%` or `%LOCALAPPDATA%` env variables. The difference is that APPDATA is part of the roaming profile - the data is saved on the user's profile in domain controller and is available if you log into another machine.  All this matters because Windows knows about those folders and can back them up, keep them during upgrades or Windows resets etc

Answer (score 2):

Use `os` library.

```py
import os

DESKTOP_PATH = os.path.expanduser("~\Desktop")

data_folder = os.path.join(DESKTOP_PATH, 'biologi')
print(data_folder)

# prints
# C:\Users\<Username>\Desktop\biologi
```